# Wavelet transform (the à trous time-based decomposition) in R

Tags: time-series, forecasting, financial

I urgently need to know how to apply the 'à trous' time-based decomposition in R [also known as [Stationary Wavelet Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_wavelet_transform)]
on a time series as a preprocessing, to use the result in forecasting and not suffering from boundary problem.

Comment: Have you looked at [wavethresh](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wavethresh/index.html)?

Comment: @BobJansen 350 pages of documentation without any examples at the front.....

Comment: At least it is well documented ;) And that why I didn't post it as an answer. There are some conciser resources though, for example: https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~wavethresh/ and one could contact the author.

Comment: @BobJansen I saw that there is a book associated with it. I may get the book just to learn more about the subject!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58040/discussion-on-question-by-ahmed-reda-wavelet-transform-the-a-trous-time-based-d).